# Is it possible for parent transaction to fail if nested transaction was successfully committed

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, transactions, nested-transactions

I'm trying to understand nested transactions in SQL Server. Lets consider following chain for SQL commands:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION; -- #1
BEGIN TRANSACTION; -- #2
UPDATE foo SET column = 'something'; -- Change something in one table.
COMMIT TRANSACTION; -- #2
```

If commit of transaction #2 succeed is it possible for commit of transaction #1 to fail? If yes, could you provide an example when this might happen?

Comment: If you're asking if transaction 2 gets rolled back even after being committed when transaction 1 is rolled back, then yes. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/527855/nested-transactions-in-sql-server

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [A SQL Server DBA myth a day: (26/30) nested transactions are real](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/a-sql-server-dba-myth-a-day-2630-nested-transactions-are-real/):

> **The commit of a nested transaction has absolutely no effect – as the only transaction that really exists as far as SQL Server is concerned is the outer one.** ...
>
> **The rollback of a nested transaction rolls back the entire set of transactions – as there is no such thing as a nested transaction.**

```
SELECT @@TRANCOUNT;
BEGIN TRANSACTION; -- #1
SELECT @@TRANCOUNT;
BEGIN TRANSACTION; -- #2
SELECT @@TRANCOUNT;
UPDATE foo SET [column] = 'something';
COMMIT TRANSACTION; -- #2
SELECT @@TRANCOUNT;
ROLLBACK;      -- simulate error or explicit rollback
               -- update is lost
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=5543b6610a6a80abeb525b10eb1ae5bf)**

If you want something like Oracle autonomous transaction please read: [Commit transaction outside the current transaction (like autonomous transaction in Oracle)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45731207/commit-transaction-outside-the-current-transaction-like-autonomous-transaction)