# Loopback connection using CLR with same user credentials, outside current transaction

Tags: sql-server, sqlclr

I want to create new connection in a clr assembly having

- same access as the current user (ie loopback using the current user credential)
- The new connection must be outside the current transaction and changes (update/insert/delete) should not be rolled back with the transaction failure

Found solutions for both cases individually

1. Use [sqlConn.ContextConnection = true;](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/clr-integration/data-access/context-connection?view=sql-server-ver16)
2. Use [sqlConn.IntegratedSecurity = true;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59498896/tsql-logging-inside-transaction-using-clr-stored-procedure)

but I want both conditions satisfied together

Basically i want to simulate autonomous connection in oracle using CLR instead of the extended stored procedure method suggested in this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45731207/commit-transaction-outside-the-current-transaction-like-autonomous-transaction/45793221#45793221)

Comment: what for, if you use the same connection. that has already windows identification. you don't need to accredit it again. so you can keep it aon false

Comment: If i have logged in using sql server authentication and called a clr stored procedure, i want the new loopback connection inside the clr also be created to allow access to that users objects only. Also I'm not sure what same connection means  as i will definitely create a new connection inside clr ans what is aon?

Comment: @Kaarthik Have you tried the loopback linked server suggestion in that other question you linked to? (i.e. https://stackoverflow.com/a/45731695/577765 )? Also, to confirm, you are using SQL Server logins and not Windows logins?

Comment: Doesn't `Integrated Security` with a context connection already do exactly this? Or if you are not authenticated as the correct user, can you not just do `EXECUTE AS`

Comment: @SolomonRutzky i want it to work with all types of logins.

Comment: @Charlieface Context connection makes it run as part of the same transaction. Meaning the rollback in the sql calling code rollbacks changes made in the clr. At least that is what i'm seeing

Comment: Without a context connection then, but with Integrated Security?

Comment: if you have sql authentificatio, then integred security isn't needed at all

Comment: Kaarthik, you will need to try that linked server option I mentioned, which sets the linked server to not promote remote transactions. The SQLCLR issue is: 1) a Context Connection is the same security context but no way to opt out of an active transaction (that I know of, but haven't tried in years setting `EnlistTransaction = false`), and 2) regular connection with Integrated Security can opt out of transaction, _but_ while can be same login IF using impersonation, that works _only_ for Windows Logins -- SQL Server logins will connect as service account of SQL Server. (CC @Charlieface)

Comment: @SolomonRutzky Annoyingly there is `SqlContext.WindowsIdentity` which only provides the user if it was a Windows User. There seems no way to get hold of a SQL User and therefore no way to do `EXECUTE AS`.

Comment: You could SELECT USER_NAME() over the context connection, and use that for impersonation in the non-context connection.  And EnlistTransaction only interacts with System.Transactions, so won't help.